# How to install libgdiplus on CentOS 7?

Tags: command-line, apt, yum

I am totally new to CentOS, and I need to install `libgdiplus` on CentOS 7?
The application which I am running needs this package.

I was able to install it on Ubuntu, by using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdiplus
```

But when I run following command on CentOS, it says package not found.

```
sudo yum install libgdiplus
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Sorry, we only accept questions for Ubuntu OS. Please try [su] or [unix.se] site instead